# Swift issue when set an image as background programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to set an image as background to the whole controller so I've written the code which I enclosed below and works fine on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

But surprisingly that wouldn't work as expected on iPhone X and the image was cut off at the bottom of the screen so I tried to modify UIImageView `contentMode` but there was no result.

Please take a look at the screenshot to see the simulators:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let img = UIImageView(frame: holderView.bounds)

img.image = UIImage(named: "step 2")

img.contentMode = .scaleToFill

holderView.addSubview(img)
```

The holderView was pinned in Interface Builder into the fourth edges of superview.

Any ideas to fix it but I don't want to use auto-layout here because this is a simple case to illustrate the issue and it would be a complex one.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `contentMode` to `scaleToFill` if you want to display the entire image irrespective of the displayed device. Also, constraint the `UIImageView` to it's superview `UIView`.

```
let img = UIImageView(frame: holderView.bounds)
img.contentMode = .scaleToFill
img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    img.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    img.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    img.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    img.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
])
```

Comment: I've tried that earlier and there was no result so and I updated the question to add it

Comment: @YasserHomsi Have you constrained the image view? Check the update. Also, try out other `contentMode`s

Comment: no I don't want to use auto-layout here because this is a simple case to illustrate the issue and it would be a complex one

Comment: Why that issue has been occurred? I can't use  auto-layout here it's more complex and I've simplified it to ask here

Comment: Explain why you're not able to use auto-layout. Also, it doesn't matter if the code is simple or complex you just need to add the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: because this is a part of a horizontal scrollview that will be created at run time and contain a 
 number of xib files which will load the images so I wanna build it as simple as possible